# Can I create a PACT to run on a different hostname?

Tags: pact

Can I create a PACT to run on a different hostname? I have been using pact rule and keeping the hostname as localhost. But now I'm trying to create a pact for an application that can not run on localhost.

@Rule
    public PactProviderRule provider = new PactProviderRule("ServiceNowClientRestClientProvider", "localhost", 8080, this);

Is it possible to change localhost to something else, if so are there additional configurations that I need. I've tried changing tests that work on localhost to the actual hostname that the code is using but then it fails and I get a various error message "Unresolved address"  or "Cannot assign requested address: bind", or "Address in use"

Answer (score 2):

Ronald Holshausen responded with a good answer to my question. Full conversation is on Pact Google forum post:

The hostname is passed through to the HTTP server library to start an HTTP server to be the mock server. This server will be running on the same machine as the test (in fact will also be the same JVM process). The HTTP server library will use the hostname to resolve to an IP address, which will in turn resolve to a network interface on the machine which the port for the server will be bound to.

It is not as simple as a yes/no answer. It is possible to do (there are standalone mock servers you can run on another machine), but the PactProviderRule always starts a mock server on the same host as where the tests are running.

To achieve what you require, you would need to use one of the mock server implementations, and a new JUnit Rule would need to implemented (preferably extended from PactProviderRule).

There are a number of standalone pact mock servers:

https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-server

https://github.com/bethesque/pact-mock_service

https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-reference/tree/master/rust/pact_mock_server_cli

The only valid values that can be used are: the hostname of the machine where the test is running, the IP address of the machine where the test is running, localhost, 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0

If a standalone mock server is started on another machine (say from your example Hostname: test.service-now.com and Port: 80), then the PactProviderRule will need to know that it should not try start a new mock server but communicate with the one is has been provided with (via the address https://test.service-now.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can in the ruby version using [pact-provider-proxy](https://github.com/bethesque/pact-provider-proxy). However, the best use case for consumer driven contracts is when you have development control over both the consumer and the provider, and this generally means that you can stand up an instance of the provider locally. If you are trying to test a public API, or an API you don't have development control over, pact may not be the best tool for you. You can read more [here](https://github.com/realestate-com-au/pact/#what-is-it-not-good-for) about what pact is *not* good for.

Comment: To clarify, you still run the consumer tests against a mock provider on localhost (whatever implementation you use, the mock provider will always run on localhost), however, you can verify the pact against a provider running on a remote address using a [proxy](https://github.com/bethesque/pact-provider-proxy) that runs on localhost and forwards the request to your remote server. @ronald-holshausen, is there an equivale

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter before I'd finished. @RonaldHolshausen, is there a proxy equivalent for the JVM? That would be a good go candidate.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do (there are standalone mock servers you can run on another machine), but the PactProviderRule always starts a mock server on the same host as where the tests are running.

To achieve what you require, you would need to use one of the mock server implementations, and a new JUnit Rule would need to implemented (preferably extended from PactProviderRule).

There are a number of standalone pact mock servers:
https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-server
https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-reference/tree/master/rust/pact_mock_server_cli
as well as the pact-mock_service from the Ruby implementation (I can't post the link due to reputation restrictions on stack overflow).